# Sum col in sql and view result in js

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a code

```js
listholder.innerHTML = mydb.transaction(function(t) {
            t.executeSql("SELECT SUM(make) AS total FROM carsplus");
            
        });
```

I want paste listholder sum of col "make".

In browser i see "undefined".

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, that is why you are seeing undefined.  I'm not sure how `executeSql` works but maybe `return t.executeSql("SELECT SUM(make) AS total FROM carsplus");`

Answer (score 0):

when executing a `SELECT` request in the `executeSql()` method , so you're expecting a data in return which we put it in the core of the executeSql as parameter , else you can not get any result !! maybe that approach could help you

```
mydb.transaction(function(t){
   t.executeSql("SELECT SUM(make) AS total FROM carsplus" , [] , function(t,data){
        console.log(data.rows.item(0).total);
    });
});
```

where the data is the full object returning by the query and the rows.item(0).total because your expecting just one value which is the SUM !!
and now so you have the result you can store in a `var x = data.rows.item(0).total` and then you do your innerHTML as know .
hope it helped .